# RadListView and JSON data from a HTTP request

Tags: json, angular, http, nativescript

I am working on an mobile app that should have a RadListView UI component filled with JSON data procured from an HTTP request. The JSON data that is at the URL address looks like this:

```
{"dataset": {
  "table": [
  {
    "CustomerNumber": 1,
    "Name": "Rudy",
  }
 }
}
```

All I get when I try to fill my RadListView with the data is "object Object" times the number of **size parameter** I request in the URL.

This is how I am trying.

```
ngOnInit() {
    getJSON("http://192.168.10.18:8100/web/data?be=customer&size=5").then(
        (r: any) => {
            this._dataItems = new ObservableArray(r.dataset.table);
            console.log("test: " + r.dataset.table[1]);      // test: [object Object]
            console.log("test2: " + this._dataItems.length);   // test2: 5
            }, 
        (e) => {
            console.log(e);
            }
    );
}
```

Any help is really appreciated as I have been stuck on this for a while and don't really know where to start.

Comment: It is expected when you concat string and object. If you want to see the real value as JSON, use comma instead of + (string concatenation) Or stringify the object before logging.

Comment: @Manoj But that doesn't solve the problem when assigning it to _dataItems. How do I pass the JSON in the ObservableArray constructor?

Comment: To be precise, you should pass Array to ObserveableArray constructor, I guess you are doing that already. If you still have issues, please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: I have assigned the fetched JSON to an array.

`this.data = new Array(r.dsCustomer.ttCustomer);`


And then gave _dataItems a new constructor 

`this._dataItems = new ObservableArray(this.data);`

What I get now in my RadListView

`[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`


Should I post a playground sample?

Comment: Ok so it turns out that I had NOT imported in the right module.ts file. I should have imported everything in my `component-name.module.ts` rather that `app.module.ts`. This was causing my data to show up as [object Object] rather than what I fetched from the URL. Thanks again for the help